# Using pictures from Wikimedia commons?

Tags: copyright, photography, copyright-notice

I'm writing a book (script for students) about art that will be published. I have a lot of images from Wikimedia Commons (photos of sculptures,...). Most of them are licenced so that "You must give appropriate credit to the author." But often just a user who uploaded the image is just "user123123" or "mike" or something similar has uploaded the image.

Must I give credit and how?

If it is a picture of a sculpture or a building (church,..).

Answer (score 1):

You should read the specific licenses to know what the conditions are. The license for [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LuettePalatineUvula.svg) is CC BY SA 3.0, where the full license is [here](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode). What you must do is

> keep intact all copyright notices for the Work and provide, reasonable
> to the medium or means You are utilizing: (i) the name of the Original
> Author (or pseudonym, if applicable) if supplied, and/or if the
> Original Author and/or Licensor designate another party or parties
> (e.g., a sponsor institute, publishing entity, journal) for
> attribution ("Attribution Parties") in Licensor's copyright notice,
> terms of service or by other reasonable means, the name of such party
> or parties; (ii) the title of the Work if supplied; (iii) to the
> extent reasonably practicable, the URI, if any, that Licensor
> specifies to be associated with the Work, unless such URI does not
> refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work;
> and (iv) , consistent with Ssection 3(b), in the case of an
> Adaptation, a credit identifying the use of the Work in the Adaptation
> (e.g., "French translation of the Work by Original Author," or
> "Screenplay based on original Work by Original Author"). The credit
> required by this Section 4(c) may be implemented in any reasonable
> manner; provided, however, that in the case of a Adaptation or
> Collection, at a minimum such credit will appear, if a credit for all
> contributing authors of the Adaptation or Collection appears, then as
> part of these credits and in a manner at least as prominent as the
> credits for the other contributing authors.

In this case, I guess they didn't read the license; or, they think that it is unreasonable to link to the original source; or, there is some behind the scenes agreement between Lamiot and Glrx. The theory in this case is that you can trace from Glrx to the photographer, via these links. "And/or" simply mean you have to do at least one of those things e.g. give the name of the Licensor, *or pseudonym* which is applicable here.

So yes, you must give credit. Include the information (name, title, url) in the book, either next to the picture, or in a table of credits.